# JBoss Resteasy Json Client, how to set: FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES

Tags: java, json, client, jboss7.x, resteasy

I have a WebService project running on JBoss 7.1. It accesses another JSON WebService. I'm using RestEasy. Maven Project. I known that extra fields will be added to the JSON webservice I'm calling. I want my software to be able to handle this. (just skip unknown fields)

I would like to set the DeserializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES for this.

I known I have to set it on ObjectMapper. Question is: How?
I cannot find a way to get it from Resteasy (ResteasyClient)
I cannot find a way to set/register a new ObjectMapper.

I have tried creating a custom ContextResolver:

```
@Provider
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class JacksonIgnoreResolver implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper> {
    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    public JacksonIgnoreResolver() throws Exception
    {
        System.out.println("JacksonIgnoreResolver constructor called!");
        objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.configure(DeserializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
    }

    @Override
    public ObjectMapper getContext(Class<?> arg0)
    {
        System.out.println("JacksonIgnoreResolver.getContext called!");
        return objectMapper;
    }    
}
```

I tried different ways to register it. I don't have a web.xml (this is client side) Ended up with:

```
JacksonIgnoreResolver resolver = new JacksonIgnoreResolver();
ResteasyProviderFactory.getInstance().registerProviderInstance(resolver);
```

The constructor is called, but the function getContext is not, so it is still not used..

Code calling the JSON webservice:

```
BasicHttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
DefaultHttpClient def = new DefaultHttpClient();
ApacheHttpClient4Engine engine = new ApacheHttpClient4Engine(def, localContext);
ResteasyClient client = new ResteasyClientBuilder()
        .httpEngine(engine)
        .build();

JacksonIgnoreResolver resolver = new JacksonIgnoreResolver();
ResteasyProviderFactory.getInstance().registerProviderInstance(resolver);

ResteasyWebTarget web_target = client.target(baseURI + getCustomerUrl);
Customer customer = web_target.request(javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .buildGet()
        .invoke(Customer.class);
```

I must be missing something, this should be very simple. I guess that most JSON clients will be configured this way.